# Email with nodemailer fails on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, nodemailer

In my node.js-App, that runs on 1 Heroku worker, needs to send out emails from time to time. The logic is the following:

```
var transporter = Email.createTransport({
    service: 'yahoo',
    auth: {
        user: process.env.CRAWLER_MAIL,
        pass: process.env.CRAWLER_PWD
    }
});
transporter.sendMail({
                            from: process.env.CRAWLER_MAIL,
                            to: process.env.CRAWLER_RCVR_MAIL,
                            subject: 'subject',
                            text: 'text'
                        }, function(err, result) {
                            if (err !== null) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                ...
                            }
                        });
```

I tested this with `foreman start` and it worked fine. Nonetheless, once deployed to Heroku, the transporter always emits an error with status code '564  :  We were unable to deliver your message. Please try resending your message by adding some text.'

`process.env.` hold the correct values, I checked for that, and `text` is always a string.

What could be wrong?

Comment: BTW, that error message is specific to Yahoo SMTP servers.

Comment: I wonder if the service is case sensitive... Did you try `service: 'Yahoo'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to replicate your problem using my account details.

Could it be related to the sender/recipient emails? Are they both @yahoo.com addresses?
There has been some chatter in forums about yahoo groups emails specifically not working and giving that error. Something to do with Yahoo changing their [DMARC](http://dmarc.org/) policy recently.

[Nodemailer](http://npmjs.org/package/nodemailer) loads predefined "well known" services from submodule [nodemailer-wellknown](http://npmjs.org/package/nodemailer-wellknown)

This is the current definition loaded when using `service: 'yahoo'` in your `createTransport()`:
https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-wellknown/blob/master/services.json#L160

A few thing worth trying:

- Switch the smtp server to `plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com`.
- Try the username with and without `@yahoo.com`
- Make sure you are sending from a real email address - and not an alias.

We use [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/pricing/) for SMTP on Heroku with our Nodemailer app.

Very reliable and the **first 12k emails sent per month are free!**

Comment: Yes, most likely the problem is associated with one of these config settings and/or with a restrictive policy of Yahoo. In the meantime, I switched to the SMTP server of my university, and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using it without the service option and specifying the SMTP sever manually as shown below.

```
var transporter = Email.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.CRAWLER_MAIL,
        pass: process.env.CRAWLER_PWD
    }
}));
```

I had this problem some time ago and was solved when I bypassed the service

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

I know it looks same but there are small changes that might solve your problem. Give it a try as it worked fine with foreman start and do let me know if it did any good...

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = Email.createTransport({
service: 'yahoo',
auth: {
    user: 'process.env.CRAWLER_MAIL',
    pass: 'process.env.CRAWLER_PWD'
}
});
transporter.sendMail({
from: 'process.env.CRAWLER_MAIL',
to: 'process.env.CRAWLER_RCVR_MAIL',
subject: 'subject',
text: 'text'
 });
```